# How does Node.js know that I have a certain package installed?

Tags: node.js

I've mostly been using node in a text editor. But I was playing around with Node in the terminal today, and I typed: `let Web3 = require('web3');` which is a package. I was not expecting this to work, but it did. How does node know that I have this package...did I install it globally before?

And what "environment" am I in when I run node on the terminal? Is it my current working directory? (I'm asking because when I run `npm install [package]` I know that that package is installed locally in my project directory, but not elsewhere)

Comment: Was node.js install locally too or globally

Comment: Was node.js install locally too or globally

Comment: try ```npm list -g``` to see your packages

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages globally(system wide). These are available system wide. So you may have installed web3 globally.

To install globally you need to use -g flag like this

`npm install -g web3`

> And what "environment" am I in when I run node on the terminal? Is it my current working directory?

Yes node starts where you run `node`. Module resolution depends on the start location as well.

Module resolution algorithm in detail:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Answer (score 0):

Directories with a package.json files treated by npm as a project folder. So, that means three things:

1. Your environment is not a working directory, but the one with a package.json file in it.
2. Calling `npm install [package]` will install this package in a `node_modules` folder on the same level as package.json file.
3. Node has a module resolution system which will look for required package in closest `node_modules` folder and some other places.

If you are interested in how it works in more details [here is a nice article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/)